# Type enumeration in VHDL

Tags: vhdl, fpga, enumeration

What is the type enumeration in the VHDL?
where can I use it, to make the code shorter and more understandable? 
for example, consider a bellow statement:

```
TYPE st_State IS (st_Idle, st_CheckHeader1, st_CheckHeader2, st_ReceiveData)
```

when must to use it.

Comment: Not a statement, it's a type declaration. An enumerated type is a scalar with values that are named. For instance std_ulogic which is the base type of std_logic is a character enumerated type. Array type string has elements of the same subtype, enumerated type character.  An enumerated type declares both the type and it's enumeration values which can make for smaller code. It can certainly be more understandable, imagine using numerical values instead of value names that are character literals.

Comment: The meaning of an enumeration literal (an identifier or character literal) is determined by context. VHDL is strongly typed and there's no need to put prefixes (e.g. st_) on enumeration literals.

Comment: Enumerated types are usually used for state machines in digital logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example is only a declaration of a type with name `st_State` and this type contains four elements. Each element gets a number from `0` to `Elements - 1`. This is similar to a C `typedef` with an C `enum`.

Please check [this](https://www.csee.umbc.edu/portal/help/VHDL/declare.html) explanation for more detailed information.

A typical application for this is a state machine to name the different states:

```
architecture Top_Arch of Top is
    type State_Type is (S0, S1, S2, S3);
    signal CurrentState : State_Type := S0; 
begin
    process(Clock)
    begin
        if(rising_edge(Clock)) then
            case CurrentState is
                when S0 =>  ...
                when S1 =>  ...
                when S2 =>  ...
                when S3 =>  ...  
            end case;
        end if;
end Top_Arch;
```

Using this method result in a more readable and cleaner code, but it is equivalent to this approach (untested):

```
architecture Top_Arch of Top is
    signal CurrentState : INTEGER RANGE 0 to 3 := 0; 
begin
    process(Clock)
    begin
        if(rising_edge(Clock)) then
            case CurrentState is
                when 0 =>  ...
                when 1 =>  ...
                when 2 =>  ...
                when 3 =>  ...  
            end case;
        end if;
end Top_Arch;
```

> NOTE: Check the `range` statement. You have to use it, because you have to declare each value for your state machine. So you have to use `when others` or reduce the integer to 2 bits only. Otherwise you have to declare `2^32 - 1` states.

So you need at least a type declaration with `type <YourType> is ...` to declare your custom type and a signal to use your type (`CurrentState` in the above example).

Comment: thanks a lot your answer is very helpful. I learned a lot from the answer study.

Answer (score 1):

Enumerated types have many other uses than just states in state machines.

You can use them as index types in arrays, loop variables, etc. For example,

```
type channel is (R,G,B);
Colour : array(channel) of byte;

constant Black : Colour := (R => 0, G => 0, B => 0);

signal VGA_Out : Colour;

-- in a process
for c in channel loop
   VGA_Out(c) <= A(c) + B(c);  -- mix video signals A and B
end loop;
```

and so on